# try to remove the string from link but its not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i am trying to remove the `pagenum=2` from the url, the value `2` can be dynamic with the following url

```
var urlval = $(this).attr('data-rel').replace(/[\?&]pagenum=\d*/g, '');
```

but the above link when i make an alert is coming like this

```
contents.cfm?up=http%3A%2F%2Fmypage.com.com%2Fez_9.asp%3Frpttype%3D298%26sortBy%3D1%26sortOrder%3D1%26pagenum%3D3
```

but it always include `pagenum`, something is wrong which i am not sure what is not working

update is: itnenever removes

```
http://www.example.com/2.asp?na_id=aaa&password=cc&target=ez_9.asp&rpttype=298&action=SUBMIT&sortBy=1&sortOrder=2&pagenum=4&pagenum=-1
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to decodeURIComponent first before running the replace. Something like:

```
var urlval = decodeURIComponent($(this).attr('data-rel')).replace(/[\?&]pagenum=\d*/g, '');
```

Comment: as i said decoded string comes sometimes, not everytime, so if there is no decoded string, it will not hurt, right

Comment: it does remove the pagenum, not sure what is the problem

Comment: The original issue was that regex pattern was not matching when encoded... It doesn't hurt to use decodeURIComponent on urls.  While testing with pagenum=-1, I noticed you'd need toalso  change the regex to `(/[\?&]pagenum=\-?\d*/g, '')` (added **\-?**) to handle negative numbers...